# How to display "Not Found" instead of automatic redirecting?

Tags: htaccess, redirects

> how to redirect to 404 in .htaccess file ? Example
>
> www.domain.com/ja/any_post or www.domain.com/ja/all_posts
>   www.domain.com/fr/any_post or www.domain.com/fr/all_posts

A little bit more explaining can't hurt. Example:

My original post is on URL `www.domain.com/post`.

I had japanese translation of it at this URL: `www.domain.com/ja/post`.
And also French translation: `www.domain.com/fr/post`.

I had to delete these translated posts and now when I type `www.domain.com/ja/post` to my address bar manually, URL is redirected automatically to original post at `www.domain.com/post`. The same goes for `/fr/`.

I need URL to stay `www.domain.com/ja/post` and show "Not found" for all posts (with `/ja/` and `/fr/` in URL) without using 301 to 404.php.

Here's my htaccess (WordPress):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Another thing I forgot to point out.../ja/ and /fr/ don't really exist.

Comment: Sorry. Question is edited. Better?

Comment: If the request is already being "redirected automatically" then there must be some code in place (maybe in your CMS?) that is performing the redirect - this is not default behaviour. Removing this "redirection" should result in the default 404.

Comment: Maybe trouble is with canonical url redirection. Wordpress automatically tries to guess url. However, it would be nice not to turn that off completely but to add an exception.

Comment: "WordPress tries to guess the URL" - Really?! "canonical url redirection" - This sounds possible, but why would the original language page bet set as the canonical? This sounds like a WordPress issue. It should be possible to override this in .htaccess, however, I think it is better resolved in WordPress itself. (?)

Comment: Tried to ask this question on their support forum...almost a week passed - no single answer from them. When canonical redirection is turned off, URL stays with /ja/ (example) but the post is in English. And you can guess what's the trouble then - duplicate content.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method would be:

```
# Redirect to HTTP 404 File/Page Not Found
Redirect 404 "/ja/any_posts"
Redirect 404 "/ja/all_posts"
Redirect 404 "/fr/any_posts"
Redirect 404 "/fr/all_posts"
```

Though you could also use:

```
# Redirect to HTTP 404 File/Page Not Found
RewriteRule ^ja/any_posts$ - [R=404,L]
RewriteRule ^ja/all_posts$ - [R=404,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/any_posts$ - [R=404,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/all_posts$ - [R=404,L]
```

Or this can be written more efficiently as:

```
RewriteRule ^(fr|ja)/(all|any)_posts$ - [R=404,L]
```

Or if you meant to redirect every page in those subfolders then:

```
RewriteRule ^(fr|ja)/(.*?)$ - [R=404,L]
```

Edited following comments:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(fr|ja)/(.*?)$ - [R=404,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work. :(

Comment: I think you're taking it too literly, I think the part after `ja|fr/` is variable.

Comment: Of course :D Can you please checkout htaccess I posted in question?

Comment: I think you edited the question after I had started writing my answer :)

Comment: :D Yea, maybe. Still doesn't work. :( I don't know what could be a problem. My permissions are 644, I think that's ok...

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what is it doing exactly? If you put some URLs with and without the fr/ja into www.urivalet.com to analyse the response headers, what do you get?

Comment: SERVER RESPONSE: 301 Moved Permanently (for /ja) . . . then requests redirect to original post....Oh Sweet Baby Jesus...I stepped into unknown area for me...

Comment: It appears as though the .htaccess file you're editing is not the one being used by Wordpress, or perhaps Wordpress is overwriting your changes? Can you access and post the Apache raw access log entries for a request like this?

Comment: Not sure how to do that... Im trying to find some of them via Cpanel. EDIT: I've found something...gimme a moment please.

Comment: not sure if this is what you were looking for...[22/Oct/2014:16:09:13 +0200] "GET /ja/panasonic/panasonic-lumix-gm5/ HTTP/1.1" 301 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36"

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines might do what you want. This will redirect the user to the 'main' version of the page, and add a 404 header in the process, removing the old link:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(ja|fr)/
RewriteRule ^(ja|fr)/(.*?) /$2 [L, R=404]
```

Comment: Same here. Doesn't work for some reason...

Comment: Maybe I'm placing code in wrong place. Ive posted my htaccess in question...

Comment: Your code rewrites it all to the index.php, and then my code fails (I test if it starts with `(ja|fr)`, which it now doesnt). My code needs to go first

Comment: Minor point, by specifying `R=404`, the user won't be "redirect[ed] to the 'main' version of the page". The substitution is ignored (should really specify `-` as pass through). The default 404 will be served and the URL will remain unchanged (since no redirection occurs). This would seem to be the desired result.

Comment: Maytbe I'm doing something wrong...still no success.

Comment: If its of any help - I got server header response SERVER RESPONSE: 301 Moved Permanently and redirecting to original post. Maybe thats the problem? Tbh I'm not familiar with server header stuff...

Comment: @Martijn Not sure why you rolled back. What you had (`R=404`) was correct, except for the `RewriteRule` substitution.

Comment: Can you please post previous version of code?